# Nilpotent matrix similar to a matrix $[0,X]$ where $X$ is full column rank.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to prove that a nilpotent matrix $N$, which has a Jordan Form consisting only of blocks which are order 2 or greater, is always similar to a matrix $\begin{bmatrix}0 & X\end{bmatrix}$ where $X$ is full column rank. So essentially the purpose is just to be able to always shift all the zero columns to the left when we have more than one Jordan block with eigenvalue zero.

I have had some success by letting \begin{equation} X=\begin{bmatrix} I_{\text{r}(N)} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ D \end{bmatrix},\end{equation} where $D$ consists of ones placed on the superdiagonal in the last few columns. Here is an example:
\begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix} \approx \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

I have managed to make this work with various different arrangements of $D$ for any matrix $N$ with the given properties, but when following this constructive route it ends up becoming a messy combinatorial argument in terms of the amount and sizes of Jordan blocks in $N$...While I am not against such a proof I was hoping there is perhaps a much simpler argument that I am currently missing - maybe in terms of a more linear algebra approach, where there is a specific useful basis, or....even if someone can perhaps just point me to some useful articles/sources of similar problems I would really appreciate it. BTW, the restrictions on $N$ need also not be there, if it can be proved for a general nilpotent matrix that is also fine.

Comment: The order of the columns in the Jordan form can be chosen to be any order by permuting the elements of the basis. So any column that is zero can be put at the beginning. In other words, take a basis in which the matrix is in Jordan form and such that all vectors which are mapped to zero are at the beginning of the basis.

Comment: @Alamos can you prove that for the example matrix I used - take the Jordan form on the right and shift the second column to one to the right...does the new matrix still have the same Jordan form?

Comment: To write less I will truncate to a $4\times 4$ matrix. The business with the $7\times 7$ is the same. Suppose $\{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_3,e_4\}$ is the basis in which the matrix is the matrix on the right. Then change basis to the basis $\{e_1,e_3,e_2,e_4\}$. The matrix that sends the first basis to the second is $$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ So, that is the matrix that gives you the similarity.

Comment: @Alamos please humor me. You are saying I can take: \begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
and then change it to this \begin{equation}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
but that does not work - the new matrix is similar to another Jordan form

Comment: So no, you can't just change columns in a Jordan form, since it is not (necessarily) diagonal. For example by changing columns in a Jordan form it is easy to see that you can actually change the eigenvalues. What you CAN permute is the diagonal blocks...

Comment: What I meant to say is that the zero columns go to the front. It is not exactly permutation of the columns what happens. Take the (permutation) matrix I wrote and apply it to the $4\times4$ matrix from the left and the right. You get $$\begin{pmatrix}0,0,1,0\\0,0,0,1\\0,0,0,0\\0,0,0,0\end{pmatrix}$$ What you do permute is the basis in which the matrix is written.

Comment: For the $5\times 5$ example in your comment the permutation matrix would be $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$ and the resulting matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me put the proof here so that it is not just hidden in the comments.

Assume that $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ is a basis in which the matrix is Jordan. Let $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}$ be the vectors of this basis that are in the kernel. Then the matrix is as you want when written in the basis $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}, ...$, where the other vectors of the basis have been placed after $e_{i_k}$.

The matrix $P$ needed to get from the Jordan form to the desired form would be the permutation matrix that sends $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_n\}$ to $\{e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}, ...\}$.

Why does this work? It is clear that the first $k$ columns of the matrix are now zero. The remaining columns are linearly independent because they send the remaining vectors of the basis, the ones that are not $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}$ to other vectors of the basis $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$.

---

**This part is just my comment above which is not displaying properly.**

For the $5\times 5$ example in your comment the permutation matrix would be $P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$ and the resulting matrix $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Well, thanks for your comments...to summarize you suggest that it is possible by using a permutation matrix alone, but unfortunately you cannot provide a general proof for this? I will look into it and see if it is indeed possible...

Comment: @ChristiaanHattingh The proof is simple. Assume that $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$ is a basis in which the matrix is Jordan. Let $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}$ be the vectors in of the basis that are in the kernel. Then the matrix is as you want when written in the basis $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}, ...$, where the other vectors of the basis have been placed after $e_{i_k}$. Why does this work? It is clear that the first $k$ columns of the matrix are zero. The remaining columns are linearly independent because they send the remaining vectors of the basis ...

Comment: ... the ones that are not $e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_k}$ to other vectors of the basis $e_1,e_2,...,e_n$. That is the proof.

Comment: Thanks I think you are right...I notice that in terms of the resulting matrix what is happening is that the zero columns become zero rows in at the same position, ie if we have a zero column as column 3, in the new matrix we have a zero row at row 3...I just want to check one or two more things and then i will accept your answer as correct.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me see the light! Basically an even easier way to see that this works: $P$ is a permutation matrix corresponding to elementary column operations that move all the zero columns in $N$ to the left...so $NP=[0,X_1]$ and now $P^{-1}$ performs row exchanges to $NP$ which does not change the 0 columns at all...again thanks very much...

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer my own question with a slightly alternative interpretation of the result as given by Alamos, in case it might be of some use to others in future:
Let $P$ be a permutation matrix corresponding to elementary column operations that will move all zero columns in $N$ to the left. Then $NP=[0,X_1]$ with $X_1$ full column rank. Now $P^{-1}$ will also be a permutation matrix and its action by left multiplication on $NP$ will be to permute the rows of $NP$, therefore leaving all zero columns at the left of $NP$ in the same position. So $P^{-1}NP=[0,X]$ with $X$ full column rank, as desired.